# Fill existing Mail Merge Word Document with ListView control Data?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, ms-office, mailmerge

I have created a simple C# Windows Forms Applicaiton that queries data from a 400 system and returns the results in a ListView control. I am now attempting to process this data into an already existing Mail Merge Word Document. Anyone have experience with this sort of thing that could help me out? This is my first time with Mail Merge.

Some similar applications I've looked over use the Word Document by writing first the Headers and then the query result records to a .txt file, which is then used as the source for the Mail Merge Word Document. Like I said, I've never messed with Mail Merge before, but, wouldn't it be possible to process the records in my ListView directly into the Mail Merge operation?

Comment: To use Word MailMerge "out of the box" Word can only use data that it gets in certain ways. None of those ways supports getting data from any kind of in-memory object, unless you happen to have an OLE DB provider or ODBC driver that does that. In this case, how are you getting the data from the "400 system" (do you mean an IBM series 400 system or whatever they call them now?)? If you are using OLE DB or ODBC, you may be able to set up a suitable connection using Word OpenDataSource.

Comment: If I can't set the data from memory, I'm willing to do the alternate route of placing all the data with headers into a delimited .txt file. The thing is I can't figure out how to in code use this .txt file for the MailMerge. The MailMerge Document already exists, I'm simply trying to find in C# how to open the word document, fill the MailMerge with my data from the .txt file, and then set the document to print.

Comment: You have to use Word's OpenDataSource method to connect to the .txt file that you created. In the simplest scenario, all you should need is to provide the first parameter to that method, i.e. the path+file name - in that case, it will probably help if you use tab characters as field delimiters, CRLFs as record delimiters, and wrap data that isn't date or numeric type in double quote characters (char 34), doubling up any char 34 characters in the data. Use the MailMerge object to set the output to the printer, then use MailMerge.Execute to print.